# Como colocar um símbolo de online dentro de uma imagem flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Olá, tenho que colocar um símbolo de online dentro de uma imagem, mas não sei como fazer isso, quero algo como :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que consegui fazer foi:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu passo essa bolinha verde pra imagem, como no exemplo lá em cima, meu código:

```
 Widget _itemListOnline(String texto, String imagem){
      return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 70,
                  height: 70,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage("$imagem"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container( //Esse é o símbolo de online
                  width: 15,
                  height: 15,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 255, 0, 1),
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Text("$texto")
          ],
        ),
      );
  }
```

Comment: Utilize o Widget `Stack`, siga a resposta do @Julio.

Comment: Te aconselho  parar pelo menos 1h do teu dia para dar uma estudada em alguns Widgets básicos do Flutter. Veja essa playlist com vídeos curtinhos [Widget of the Week](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b_sQ9bMltGU&list=PLjxrf2q8roU23XGwz3Km7sQZFTdB996iG); [Widgets básicos](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/basics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É simples, você pode utilizar o widget `Stack` para isso.E com o `Positioned` controlar a posição do indicador de *online*.

```dart
return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage(
                  'https://api.adorable.io/avatars/283/abott@adorable.pngCopy to Clipboard'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: 10,
          right: 10,
          child: Container(
            width: 15,
            height: 15,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 255, 0, 1),
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja um exemplo [rodando no dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/dc8463c70587d76ab9e21c6990740d8d).